# How to hide empty with get_object_taxonomies?

Tags: wordpress, hide, categories, custom-post-type, taxonomy

Is it possible to hide taxonomies without categories. I'm using get_object_taxonomies to show all my taxonomies inside my custom post type.

```
<?php
            
        $blog_taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'blog', 'textdomain',
        (array(
            'hide_empty' => true,
        ))
    );
        
        foreach ($blog_taxonomies as $blog_taxonomy) : 
        
        ?>

            <ul class="blog__categories-list">

                <li class="blog__categories-title"> <?= $blog_taxonomy->labels->name; ?> </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below. The parameters you submitted to get_object_taxonomies are incorrect.

```
$taxonomy_objects = get_object_taxonomies('blog', 'objects');
        foreach ($taxonomy_objects as $taxonomy) {
            $taxonomy_terms = get_terms(['taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name, 'hide_empty' => true]);
            if (!empty($taxonomy_terms)) {
                return;
            }
            // Your operation
        }
```

See [get_object_taxonomies](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_object_taxonomies/) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

use `get_object_taxonomies` function like this

```
$taxonomy_objects = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post', 'product' ), 'objects' );
foreach ( $taxonomy_objects as $taxonomy ) {
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name, 'hide_empty' => true ) );
    //var_dump($taxonomy_terms);
}
```